# Reflection of light ray

Tags: optics, reflection

When we see our face in an spoon by which we eat food, we observe that the image of our face is inverted and we can see it so it is real image. So how this real inverted image is formed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does your reflection suddenly turn upside down while slowly walking away from a curved mirror?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36220/)

Answer (score 0):

The spoon is a curved mirror. Obviously, different spoons have different curves. Put your finger close to the spoon. Notice how it is right side up. As you move your finger out there will be a distance where your finger is very blurry. That's the focal point. After the focal point the image will flip. To visualize why this happens. Picture a small cone on the spoon, point side up. The point is the focal point. Notice how after the point the top rays cross to the bottom and bottom to the top.